# matlab generate fixed degree undirected graph

Tags: matlab, graph

I would like to generate the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph with N nodes.
In particular, this graph should have a fixed degree (each node is connected to a fixed number of node d).

If a set d = N-1, the solution is trivial:

```
A = ones(N) - eye(N);
```

How can I generalize it for any d?

ADD:

Here is a solution (thanks to Oli Charlesworth):

```
function A = fixedDegreeGraph(N, d)

A = zeros(N);

for i=1:N

    b = i;
    f = i;

    for k=1:floor(d/2)

        f = f + 1;
        if (f == N + 1)
            f = 1;
        end
        A(i, f) = 1;
        A(f, i) = 1;

        b = b - 1;
        if (b == 0)
            b = N;
        end
        A(i, b) = 1;
        A(b, i) = 1;

    end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even `d`, here's a way to visualise the approach.

- Draw the vertices out arranged in a circle.
- Each vertex is connected to its immediate `(d/2)` left-hand neighbours, and its immediate `(d/2)` right-hand neighbours.

It should be fairly obvious how to turn this into an adjacency matrix (hint: it will be a [*circulant matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), so you may find the [`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) function useful).

Extending this to odd `d` is not much harder... (although note [there is no solution if both `N` and `d` are odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma))

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I wrote the solution without using toeplitz (see my original post). How can I use toeplitz?